# How to use a library in multiple files in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, winston

I want to use Winston for logging in my nodejs express project. In my main file( server.js ) I have the following code :

```
const winston = require('winston');
winston.level = process.env.LOG_LEVEL
winston.log('info', 'Hello log files!')
```

I want to use this library in other files as well, so do I have to add these 2 lines to every file I want to use it or is there a better way to do it.

Comment: if im geting you right you need to create a new file and inside the file require your package then set the parameters as you want and then export it.
after that instead require the module from the npm you can require your own module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create customWinston.js File:

```
let winston = require('winston');
winston.level = process.env.LOG_LEVEL
winston.log('info', 'Hello log files!')

exports.customWinston = winston;
```

and then require your custom Winston:

```
let customWinston = require('./customWinston').customWinston;
```

Comment: Thanks! How about making it global, what are drawbacks to making it global

Comment: cant see serious drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can export and call it like this.

```
const winston = require('winston');
winston.level = process.env.LOG_LEVEL
module.exports = winston;
```

In other file

```
const winston = require('/path/to/winston');
winston.log('blah blah');
```

Or, just make it global and call it. (not recommended)

```
const winston = require('winston');
winston.level = process.env.LOG_LEVEL
global.WINSTON = winston;

...

// other file
WINSTON.log('blah')
```

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way of doing this is adding your custom logger to the winston object:

```js
var winston = require('winston');

// add a new logger to the winston object
winston.loggers.add('logger1', {
  console: {
    level: 'silly',
    colorize: true,
    label: 'Console One'
  },
  file: {
    filename: '/path/to/your/logfile.log'
    level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL
  }
}
```

After setting up your logger as described in the snippet above you can just "get" the logger in any other file in your application:

```js
var winston = require('winston');

// get your preconfigured logger
var myLogger = winston.loggers.get('logger1');

// start logging!
myLogger.error('FooError');
myLogger.log('warn', 'Exiting application');
```

This is also the way, which is described in the winston documentation: [Winston Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston)